# Like all CSS being valid SCSS, is all JS valid TS as well?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, sass

In SASS, all CSS is valid SCSS. Is TypeScript similar with all JavaScript being valid TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. So all valid JavaScript is also valid TypeScript.